# Verschwundene und verschwindende Anglizismen

Tags: anglicism

Im Zusammenhang mit der Theoriebildung über den Gebrauch von Anglizismen ist mir kürzlich der Gedanke gekommen, dass manche Anglizismen wieder aus der Sprache zu verschwinden scheinen.

Mein Beispiel dazu ist "Slomo", als Anglizismus und Abkürzung für Zeitlupe (slow motion).

Mein durchaus subjektiver Eindruck ist, dass das Wort eine Zeit lang Mode war, und nun ziemlich aus dem Sprachgebrauch wieder verschwunden ist.

Ich suche nun weitere solcher Beispiele, und da es davon viele gibt, und keine einzelne Antwort richtig ist.

Comment: Ein interessanter Gedanke. Zu dem Beispiel: Ich kann mich nicht erinnern, dass das Wort mal in Mode war, aber vielleicht bin ich zu jung (geb. 1985) oder war in der falschen peer group unterwegs. In dem Zusammenhang frage ich mich, was eine gute Quelle für Alltagssprache ist, die als Nachweis für ein Wort dienen könnte: Nur weil zum Beispiel die Werbung den Begriff "groovy" verwendet muss der nicht tatsächlich in der Alltagssprache angekommen sein, oder?

Comment: @0x6d64 Ich hingegen (Jahrgang 1970) kann mich gut an *Slomo* erinnern.

Comment: Interessant wäre dann auch, zu untersuchen, warum ein Anglizismus wieder verschwindet und ob bzw. wovon er dann ersetzt wird. Im Falle von *SloMo* könnte ich mir z. B. denken, dass der Effekt der Zeitlupe einfach nicht mehr als besonders spannend wahrgenommen wird und daher einfach weniger drüber geredet wird. Andererseits hat aber eben der Begriff *Zeitlupe* wahrscheinlich *SloMo* in der Alltagssprache weitgehend abgelöst, es sind hier also wahrscheinlich zwei Effekte zu beobachten: Das vom Anglizismus beschriebene Phänomen wird seltener diskutiert, und der Anglizismus wurde abgelöst.

Comment: Meine Suche mit Google ngram förderte keine einzige Slomo zutage - wohl weil es auf mündliche Rede von Sportreportern beschränkt blieb. @0x6d64: Solange eine einzige Firma mit "groovy" wirbt würde ich es als gescheiterten Sprachschöpfungs- oder -manipulationsversuch werten, aber wenn mehrere Firmen mit "groovy" auffielen, so würde das vielleicht schon genügen. Wörter, die man mit ngram zeigen kann, wären natürlich besonders hübsch - ansonsten sollte auf- und abwerten hier zeigen, ob eine Vielzahl zustimmt.

Comment: @fzwo: Eure Spekulationen, wieso die Anglizismen wieder verschwunden sind, sind als Kommentare oder Beiwerk in Antworten willkommen und erwünscht, aber eigenständige Antworten sollen neue Beispiele enthalten. Das Verschwinden des Begriffs Slomo wird durch einen Rückgang des Redens über Zeitlupen nicht erklärt - man würde dann seltener über Slomo reden; es sei denn es wäre ein ungeliebter Ausweichsbegriff gewesen, um sich nicht dauernd zu wiederholen. Wenn sich aber niemand mehr wiederholt braucht niemand mehr ein Synonym. Ist das so gemeint? Ich meine aber dass Slomo lustvoll verwendet wurde..

Comment: ..eher mit dem Impetus: Schaut, wie polyglot ich bin, was ich nicht alles kenne. Und wenn es dann jeder kennt macht es keinen Spaß mehr.

Comment: Ich nehme an, dass Zeitlupen einfach nichts cooles, außergewöhnliches mehr sind, und man darum auch kein cooles, außergewöhnliches Wort mehr dafür braucht, und somit zum sachlicheren Wort zurückkehren konnte. (Klar, Zeitlupen gibt es schon lange, aber wirklich praktikable Superzeitlupen gab es AFAIK erst seit Arthur Penns "The Highest" aus den frühen 70ern. Dieser Film hat die Zeitlupe zum Stilmittel erhoben und populär gemacht.) Vorher war Zeitlupe nur einem Fachpublikum bekannt, jetzt nichts besonderes mehr. Zwischendurch: Cool. (Reine Theoriefindung meinerseits)

Comment: (Leider zu spät zum Editieren: Link zu [The Highest](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6pRZCvAPlc) nachgereicht)

Comment: @0x6d64 Ich bin vor kurzem auf die Website http://www.sprachnudel.de/ gestoßen, die Begriffe und Wendungen aus verschiedenen deutschen Alltagssprachen sammelt.

Answer (score 3):

Ich fand die These zunächst ziemlich gewagt, bis mir gerade eben ein Anglizismus begegnete, der in meinen Ohren irgendwie veraltet und aus der Mode klang: die Vorsilbe **Pocket-**.

> Sie hat eine Zeitungsmeldung vom Tod ihres Vaters bei sich und einen großen Bericht über Christians Präsidenten-Wahl. Eine Lebensgeschichte im **Pocketformat**. Oder Reste davon.
>   ([Quelle](http://www.welt.de/politik/deutschland/article13450861/Die-Geschichte-der-heimlichen-Schwester.html))

Ich bin leider zu jung, um mich genauer erinnern zu können, wie verbreitet der Begriff wirklich war, aber zumindest "Pocketkamera" scheint recht populär gewesen zu sein. Dieser Begriff scheint allerdings auch von Produktbezeichnungen der Marke Kodak beeinflusst zu sein; Kodak brachte zusammen mit einem Filmformat [Pocketfilm](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocketfilm) auch eine Reihe von Kameras mit "pocket" im Namen heraus: [Liste der Kameras](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocketkamera#Modelle_und_Modellreihen)

Heute findet sich der Begriff kaum noch, außer vielleicht in Markennamen wie "Pocket Coffee", einem Produkt, das anscheinend auch etwas länger am Markt ist, wie Fernsehwerbungen von [1990](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-TFfqmrs5g), [1987](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-TFfqmrs5g) zeigen.

Comment: Pocketkamera ist auch der einzige Pocket-Begriff, den ich noch in Erinnerung habe - wobei meine Eltern dafür den aus der entsprechenden Werbung stammenden Begriff "Ritsch-Ratsch-Klick(-Kamera)" verwendet haben.

Answer (score 2):

Das ist in der Tat nicht so einfach, wie ich anfangs dachte. Hier ein paar Versuche:

**Stewardess/Steward** ist am Verschwinden.

**Macintosh** wurde früher statt "Apple" gebraucht, ist aber kein richtiger Anglizismus, auch wenn es gefühlt keine Produktbezeichnung war (etwa wie manche von uns früher *IBM* anstelle von *PC* gebrauchten).

**HiFi** wird viel seltener verwendet als zu meiner Kindheit (es gelten ja auch anglizistische Abkürzungen).

Jedenfalls macht es Spaß, darüber nachzudenken. Dufte Frage.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht ob HiFi zählt, weil es nicht abgelöst wurde durch einen anderen Begriff. Was hat Steward/Stewardess beerbt? Macintosh ist nicht der Name eines Produkts, sondern einer Produktreihe/-familie, oder nicht? Das kann man aber ganz prinzipiell nicht erfühlen, sondern nur wissen oder nicht, daher irritiert mich das "gefühlt" - was soll das ausdrücken? Dass es in Wahrheit doch eine Produktbezeichnung war, weil Gefühle meist trügen? Aber zum Topic: Produkte und Marken unterliegen ihrerseits Moden. Dass mit den Marken der Wortgebrauch schwankt ist nicht überraschend. ...

Comment: ... Man hört heute auch nicht "Kutscher!" am Straßenrand rufen, wie es noch vor 100 Jahren gang und gäbe war. :) Es geht mir also um die Änderung der Wörter, weil man sich anderer Wörter bedient, nicht weil man sich des Bezeichneten nicht mehr bedient.

Comment: Flugbegleiter duerfte Stewardess beerbt haben. Das ist allerdings parallel zur Entwicklung im englischsprachigen Raum (-> Flight attendant). Das ist vermutlich der political correctness "geschuldet".

Comment: @Jules Was ist politisch falsch an Steward u. Stewardess?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter und Facebook sind seit Jahrzehnten die ersten größeren Subräume für sprachliche Entwicklung in einem geschlossenen Raum (d. h. hauptsächlich genutzt von jüngeren Leuten bzw. verlinken sich bestimmte Altersgruppen thematisch sehr stark kommunikativ darin). Davor mussten sprachliche Entwicklungen eigentlich immer von einer Mehrheit, Branche oder größeren Altersschicht getragen werden, damit sie nachhaltig fruchten und sich z. B. bestimmte Wörter/Phrasen durchsetzten. Oft eben aus der amerikanischen Kultur stammend. Das würde deine These stützen. Ich würde sagen, dass die Jugendkultur und -sprache in den 80 und v. a. in den 90ern von Anglizismen beeinflusst wurde und es aufgrund der kommunikationstechnologischen Entwicklungen im letzten Jahrzehnt wirklich Tendenzen in spez. Bevölkerungsschichten und Altersgruppen gibt und geben kann, dass z. B. deutsche Jugendsprache und Wortschöpfung Anglizismen verdrängen in ihrem Bereich, während es in meiner Jugend eher "cool" war Anglizismen zu nutzen. "Cool" ist anscheinend mittlerweile wieder out, die Kids sagen jetzt "swag".

http://www.spiegel.de/schulspiegel/0,1518,801863,00.html
http://woerter.germanblogs.de/archive/2011/02/23/jugendsprache-die-10-besten-begriffe-und-ihre-uebersetzung.htm

Ob Anglizismen von anderen Anglizismen verdrängt oder überlagert werden oder wirklich durch deutsche Wortschöpfungen ersetzt werden, ist sicherlich eine spannende Frage. Hab ich jetzt auf die Schnelle auch nicht viel gefunden. Könntest du mal eventuell bei linguistics.SE fragen oder bei Kultur- und Kommunikationstheoretikern googlen. Wenn es den Effekt gibt, sollte er ja auch in anderen Sprach- und Kulturkreisen auftreten (kulturelle Entwicklungen werden sehr oft technologisch und systemisch getriggert), dann hast du bei ling.SE evtl. mehr Erfolg. Aufgrund der Verlagerung der Kommunikation ins Digitale müsste sich das ja auch messen lassen, wenn man die Kommunikation im heutigen deutschsprachigen Internet und dem Ende der 90er vergleicht. Selbst das mögliche Faktum, dass die Wortschöpfungsrate in der deutschen Jugendsprache gegenüber den 90ern zugenommen hätte, wäre ja schon ein Indiz, dass diese Kommunikationstechnologien die "Eigenvitalität" und Abgeschlossenheit der deutschen Jugendsprache bestärkt. Es gab ja auch in den 90ern gar kein großes dt. Internet mit vielen dt. Inhalten, das Netz wurde Englisch geboren und die Bildungselite hat die Anglizismen aufgesogen. Heute kann ja Hinz und Kunz ein Forum oder Blog installieren und Autor werden.

Wie gesagt, in der Jugendsprache wäre der Effekt imho am größten, wenn existent. Aber es scheint auch gegenläufige Trends zu geben in der oberen Altersschicht (Generation Golf), "Public Viewing", "Handy", Scheinanglizismen oder schlechtes Denglisch, wie man es eben nennen möchte. In der Wissenschaft nehmen imho Anglizismen deutlich zu.

http://www.goethe.de/ges/spa/siw/de4889778.htm
http://www.goethe.de/lhr/prj/mac/msp/de1401743.htm

PS: und Raider heißt jetzt Twix, sonst ändert sich nix ;)

Comment: Ein interessanter Diskussionsbeitrag - allein, ich suche weitere Beispiele.

Comment: @userunknown wie gesagt cool wird IMHO durch krass/swag ersetzt, aber mein Beitrag war eher gedacht wo man evtl. suchen sollte, überzeugt bin ich von deiner These noch nicht und dass es "davon viele gibt", dir aber nur slomo einfällt, was sich wie olafs Begriffe eher auf techn. engl. Neuerungen zurückzuführen lässt, überzeugt mich nicht. Das es Zeitlupe komplett verdrängt hat für Jahre wag ich zu bezweifeln. Das sind dann mehr techn. als sprachlich-soziale Entwicklungen für mich. Wenn Begriffe wie Marketing aussterben würden, aber obige Beispiele lassen sich imho leicht erklären.

Comment: Ich bleib dabei, dass solche Veränderungen nur in einer sprachlich grösseren abgeschlossen Gruppe stattfinden könnten, und die seh ich nur in der Jugendsprache wie oben erklärt, du musst ja auch die insgesamt zunehmende Verwendung von Anglizismen erklären, die deiner These stark widerspricht

Comment: Oh, ja, `swag` ist mir wieder untergegangen beim Lesen, es könnte mehr hervorgehoben sein. Was bedeutet es eigentlich? dict.leo liefert nichts hilfreiches - gehört habe ich es auch noch nie.

Comment: Ich suche auch nicht nach kompletter Verdrängung, sondern nach deutlichen Schwankungen im Sprachgebrauch. Ich finde es plausibel, dass viele Leute bei einem einmal gelernten Begriff bleiben; so sprach meine Oma noch in den 80ern von der Reichsbahn, wenn sie Bundesbahn meinte (fuhr aber auch so gut wie nie Zug).

Comment: @userunknown cooler Typ, der hat swag. In dem Link oben wird auch noch wacken für abfeiern oder Party machen genannt. Ich finds interessante Frage, würd sie aber auf linguistics.SE stellen, wenn der Effekt existiert, warum dann nur im Deutschen, de.soc.sprache gibts auch noch.